# In PHP can you terminate a loop as soon as you reach a specified number of integers?

Tags: php

```
 for( $i = 0; $i <= 10; $i++){

   echo $i."<br>";


   }
```

Is there a way I can terminate this loop when it prints the 3rd integer?

Comment: If you only want 3, then why iterate to 10? `for ($i=0; $i<= 3; $i++)`

Comment: `if (2 == $i) { break; }`

Comment: @rokas that is the 4th iteration though

Comment: Sorry, my mistake :) edited

Answer (score 1):

The second parameter in the loop is the condition that specifies the loop is still valid.

```
for( $i = 0; $i <= 2; $i++){  //Change the 10 to a 2 here.
   echo $i."<br>";
}
```

You can also break out inside a loop if there's a reason to:

```
for( $i = 0; $i <= 10; $i++){
   echo $i."<br>";
   if ($i == 2){
       break;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
for( $i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
   echo $i."<br>";
}
```

or

```
for( $i = 0; $i <= 10; $i++) {
   echo $i."<br>";
   if ($i == 2) break;
}
```

?